# Prove Cardinality of Power set of $\mathbb{N}$, i.e $P(\mathbb{N})$ and set of infinite sequences of $0$s & $1$s is equal.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory, functions, cardinals

I tried doing this by defining a function $f$ which takes an element (a subset of $\mathbb{N}$) and maps it to an infinite sequence of $0$s & $1$s. A subset, i.e the element of $P(\mathbb{N})$ will contain discrete numbers from $\mathbb{N}$ (arranged in increasing order, since the order of numbers in a subset does not change the element), The same positions as those numbers will get $1$ (become activated) and others would be $0$ (switched off). E.g: $(2,4,6,8,10,\ldots)$ will map to $(0101010101010\ldots)$, $(1,3,5,7,9)$ will map to $(10101010101\ldots)$ , $\mathbb{N}$ itself will map to $(11111111111111111\ldots)$ and null set will map to $(00000000\ldots)$. Is the approach correct? Someone asked me what if I give you an infinite sequence of natural numbers $(a,b,c,d,\ldots)$ i.e an element of $P(\mathbb{N})$, what will be its  image? What should be an ideal answer.In other words how to rigorously show that $f$ is well-defined (one-one and onto)?

Comment: Yeah this map is correct. Of course it's well defined you'll get $1$ in the $a^{\text{th}}$ position for each $a$ in the sequence and $0$ elsewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is essentially correct, but it is not very precise because you are *identifying* subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ with their increasing enumerations.  Although one could say that these two things are "essentially the same," one could also say that subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ are "essentially the same" as infinite sequences of zeroes and ones, but the challenge remains to make these relationships mathematically precise.

First we need a precise notion of "infinite sequence of zeroes and ones."  The set of such sequences can be written as $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ and we can think of its elements as *functions* from $\mathbb{N}$ to the set of digits $\{0,1\}$.  The $n$-th element of the sequence is just its *value* at the argument $n$.

Given a subset $A \subset \mathbb{N}$, we can define a corresponding element $f(A)$ of $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$.  Because $f(A)$ is supposed to be a function on $\mathbb{N}$, the way to define it is to specify its value $f(A)(n)$ at each number $n \in \mathbb{N}$.  We can do this by writing
$$ f(A)(n) = \begin{cases}
0 & \text{if } n \notin A\\
1 & \text{if } n \in A.
\end{cases}
$$

This is just a precise way of expressing what you said, namely that we put a $1$ in the positions corresponding to numbers that are in $A$ and a $0$ in the positions corresponding to numbers that are not in $A$.  Now that we have defined the function $f$, you may be able to show that it is a bijection from $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ to $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ (if you get stuck on this, please feel free to leave a comment.)

Comment: Thank you it was helpful.Initially the problem was to show a bijection(same cardinality) between P(N) and S={f:N -> {0,1}},and in the hind sight it appears I took the longer route by introducing the third set of infinite sequences of 0's and 1's(namely {0,1}N}.

Comment: @ParikshitKhanna That's barely a third set. A sequence of $1$s and $0$s *is* a function $f:\Bbb N\to{0,1}$, and vice versa.